# how to set leading zeros for hh:mm:ss:ff format?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have time codes which is in hh:mm:ss:ff format (hours:minutes:sec:frames). Most of the times whenever I recieve the time code sheets from client, it would be in h:m:ss:f format. I have to enter leading zeros wherever it is missing in the time codes. Could you please anyone help me out on quickest solution..

Example for correct format: 01:14:30:04

Example for incorrect format : 1:14:30:4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,TEXT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$4)-1)*99+1,99),"00"))
```

As an Array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

[image]

---

Without the TEXTJOIN we need to concatenate each part:

```
=TEXT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",99)),1,99),"00") & ":" & 
 TEXT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",99)),99,99),"00") & ":" & 
 TEXT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",99)),198,99),"00") & ":" & 
 TEXT(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",REPT(" ",99)),297,99),"00")
```

[image]

Comment: @LokanathK if this works for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer, It will remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving the data to a Different cell you could just use the `TEXT` formula, like so:

```
=TEXT(A2, "hh:nn:ss.0;@")
```

Another way to do it would be through the code behind, which I can go over if you need it.

Comment: `1:14:30:4` Is not a time format that Excel will recognize as a number.  Thus it is a text string and TEXT will only work on a number.  This will produce the same text as the input provided by the OP.

Comment: =TEXT(A2, "hh:nn:ss.0;@") i tried this one but i dont want dot in the time code.